# Differentiate between full name, company name, and job title

Tags: java, pattern-matching

So while on Christmas break I thought I would try and work on my programming skills. I am currently writing a program that will take input from a file with already set records like" name, company name, job title, phone number, email". These can all be in a different order. My program needs to be able to identify each of these. I have phone number and email working, but I am lost on how to differentiate between full name, company name, and job title.

With the email and phone number I used pattern matching in Java, but I am positive that would not work for the others. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: The easiest/best thing to do is to have the data follow a specific and unambiguous format. Unless your intention is to practice pattern matching?

Comment: Well I want to try to stick with pattern matching, but doing that doesnt seem practical with figuring out if if the input is a company name, full name, or job title.

Comment: @MadeleineG: Can you post some sample data from the file?

Comment: Is there is a consistent pattern by which to differentiate between the three types of field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a chance in here.
Company names and job titles are very specific.
If you create two string arrays, one for company names and one for job titles and  fill the exact values you have in that file then you can compare the file-value with the arrays.  (equalsIgnoreCase).
If match then show value with respective tags.
:)